# How to use plotly with data in Series and indexes in Timestamps

Tags: python, timestamp, series

I'm trying to plot the prices of a stock the past 5 days. I'm using yfinance to import the data with the corresponding date, every minute.

```
import yfinance as yf
data = yf.download(tickers='SOF.BR', period="5d" , interval="1m").CLose
print(data)
```

output:

```
Datetime
2021-06-24 09:00:00+02:00    360.000000
2021-06-24 09:01:00+02:00    360.200012
2021-06-24 09:02:00+02:00    360.600006
2021-06-24 09:04:00+02:00    361.399994
2021-06-24 09:05:00+02:00    361.600006
                                ...
2021-06-30 17:26:00+02:00    364.000000
2021-06-30 17:27:00+02:00    364.000000
2021-06-30 17:28:00+02:00    363.799988
2021-06-30 17:29:00+02:00    363.799988
2021-06-30 17:35:00+02:00    363.799988
```

Now if I plot this Series, the issue is thatI get these long constant lines when market closes, so i'm trying to get rid of these.

[image: graph]

Every method solving this issue I've found so far relies on the data to be in two arrays. Most solutions use plotly.graph_objects and then update the xaxis.

I have successfully tried putting my 2 columns in an array, but because the index of the Series is a Timestamp, and has this weird '+02:00' at the end it's not really usable. The array with dates looks like this:

```
[Timestamp('2021-06-24 09:00:00+0200', tz='Europe/Brussels'), Timestamp('2021-06-24 09:01:00+0200', tz='Europe/Brussels'),
Timestamp('2021-06-24 09:02:00+0200', tz='Europe/Brussels'), Timestamp('2021-06-24 09:04:00+0200', tz='Europe/Brussels'), 
Timestamp('2021-06-24 09:05:00+0200', tz='Europe/Brussels'), Timestamp('2021-06-24 09:07:00+0200', tz='Europe/Brussels'), 
Timestamp('2021-06-24 09:10:00+0200', tz='Europe/Brussels'), Timestamp('2021-06-24 09:11:00+0200', tz='Europe/Brussels'),
Timestamp('2021-06-24 09:13:00+0200', tz='Europe/Brussels'),...]
```

So my question is, how can I convert this data so I can work with it with plotly?

(Or if you think I'm searching in the wrong direction, how should I try to solve this problem?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you know the hours that need to be excluded you can use [rangebreaks](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/xaxis/) to accomplish this. It should look something like this:

```
fig.update_xaxes(rangebreaks=[dict(values=breaks)])
```

the whole code should look like this:

```
fig.update_xaxes(
    rangebreaks=[
        # Below values are bound (not single values), ie. hide x to y
        dict(bounds=["sat", "mon"]),  # hide weekends, eg. hide sat to before mon
        dict(bounds=[16, 9.5], pattern="hour"),  # hide hours outside of 9.30am-4pm
        # dict(values=["2020-12-25", "2021-01-01"])  # holidays
    ]
)
```

---

#### Usage example:

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv')

fig = go.Figure([go.Scatter(x=df['Date'], y=df['AAPL.High'])])

fig.update_xaxes(
        rangeslider_visible=True,
        rangebreaks=[
            # NOTE: Below values are bound (not single values), ie. hide x to y
            #dict(bounds=["sat", "mon"]),  # hide weekends, eg. hide sat to before mon
            #dict(bounds=[16, 9.5], pattern="hour"),  # hide hours outside of 9.30am-4pm
            dict(values=["2015-02-18", "2017-01-04"])  # hide holidays (Christmas and New Year's, etc)
        ]
    )

fig.show()
```

Comment: what would be 'fig' in my case?  I'm plotting my data in a figure using subplots, and because my data is in a Series object,  .update_xaxes doesn't work. I thought fig would be a figure, but when I use .update_xaxes on my figure it obvioulsy says AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'update_xaxes'

Comment: Hey, I added a basic usage example. fig has to be a plotly figure object.

Comment: yes but I have found your solution before in other forums, the problem is that my data isn't imported from a csv file so I can't directly use go.Scatter on my  code. Because i want the prices every minute of the past days I can't use your way af fetching data. I think I will just make a csv file from my data, will be a pain to make but no one seems to know how to use plotly with a series object.

Comment: i made it work with your solution, thanks! my x axis became x=Series.index and y=Series, and somehow this just works